# How to send data from another file to client via Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have got a function in file2.js which creates some data. This data should go to file1.js and should be sent from there to a client. How do I do that?

app.js:

```
var app    = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io     = require('socket.io')(server);
var file1  = require('./file1')(io);
```

file1.js:

```
var file2 = require('./file2');

//This is how it usually works if I want to interact with a client:
module.exports = function(io) {
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('channel_x', function (data, callback) {});
  });
}

//What if I want to send (emit) data which comes from another file to the client?
exports.functionInFile1 = function(exampleDataFromFile2) {
  //How to send "exampleDataFromFile2" to client from here?
}
```

file2.js:

```
var file1 = require('./file1');

function functionInFile2() {
  //do something
  var exampleData = {some: "data"};
  file1.functionInFile1(exampleData);
}

functionInFile2();
```

Comment: `file1` - First of all you can't use `module.exports =` and `exports.functionInFile1 =` together, `exports.functionName` won't be available while requiring this file.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you provide `io` instance to `file2` while requiring it just like `file1` and then send data to client from there itself.

`file2.js`

```
function functionInFile2(io) {
    //do something
    var exampleData = { some: "data" };
    io.emit('message', exampleData);
}

module.exports = functionInFile2;
```

`file1.js`

```
var functionFile2 = require('./file2');

module.exports = function(io) {
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('channel_x', function(data, callback) { });
    });
    functionFile2(io);
}
```

Comment: This does not make sense to me because `functionInFile2();` should be executed in `file2.js` (as soon as I get a response from another function)